# Deploy multiple smart contract vs reuse a single one?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Should I treat a smart contract as an instance or a reuseable service?

Example, for the application that allows users to play a game with other users and wager some coins.

Does each match deploy a new smart contract?

Or we deploy smart contract only once, call function and store data in an array ( given that match time is short), delete the data in the array when the match is done?

Answer (score 1):

depending on what are you trying to do, some cases like libraries you can deploy one contract and use it in as many contracts you want, other libraries are imported and used directly like safemath, it depends on what you are trying to do and how you want to handle the trade off of each solution

Comment: What is some trade-off between the two solutions? I assume deploy multiple smart contracts will have higher gas fee?

Comment: One trade-off is that deploying a whole new contract costs a lot. If you need to do it often it makes sense to try to reuse. The address is different for each deployment so you need to have a way to propagate it to users too. On the other hand redeploying a contract gives you a chance to use an updated version without having to use a proxy.